# Drag and Drop in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am working on drag and drop in react.I am able to drag the component from one division to the other division successfully.But,while dragging the component from parent division,the component is visible in parent division.When i drop the component to the target division then the component will disappear from the parent division.My requirement is that ,to make appear the component only once i.e when i start dragging it should disappear from parent division.How can I achieve that.Below is the code to achieve drag and drop .Help would be appreciated.

```
dragStart(event) {
    var bg=document.getElementById("bg")
    bg.style.transform=null
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
    }
    allowDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    drop=(event)=> {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
      event.target.appendChild(data);
      data.style.position="fixed";
      data.style.left = (event.clientX - data.clientWidth / 2) + "px";
      data.style.top = ( event.clientY- data.clientHeight / 2) + "px";
      console.log(event.target.getBoundingClientRect())
      console.log(event)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible

Refer to the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint: don't post link-only answers. Instead copy the essential parts from the target side here, to avoid invalidating an answer when the link target disappears.

Comment: Okay @MikeLischke, Thanks for your valuable feedback.